# VHDL clock divide in decimal

Tags: vhdl, clock

I need to divide the 50 MHz clock to 1.5 Mhz with 50% duty cycle using VHDL. For that I wanted to use a counter to count the number of 50 Mhz clock pulses until half of the 1.5 Mhz clock period i.e 16.6666 which is in decimal which I don't know how to implement in the code. Can any one please help me with it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in VHDL but I don't think you can get exactly to 1.5 MHz with synthesizable code. You could maybe get an average of 1.5 MHz if you vary how many clock cycles you wait on the 50 MHz clock until you raise the 1.5 MHz one.

If you only want code that can be simulated then of course you can just use arbitrary delays.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are suggesting will result in an approximation, which may of course be ok. If not, I would suggest you use instantiate a PLL or clock manager specific to the target technology.

Comment: PLL is the way to go. If you implement the clock divider yourself, the best you can get is an approximation. If you're using Altera design software look for the ALTPLL megafunction.

Comment: I am using Xilinx ISE. DCM can divide only till 16. So, I cannot divide by 33.3333 to get 1.5 MHz from 50MHz input clock. Do you know how to implement this using DCM?

Comment: Use the DCM_clkgen primitive: set M = 3, d = 10 (i've read the data sheet, this is valid). This will take your 50MHz reference, increase its frequency to 150MHz, and divide by 10 giving 15MHz. Then either do a 5 clock counter to give you 1.5MHz, which will probably be ok at those speeds, or put a second dcm and further divide down.